# Linearmodels value error - do not have full column rank

Tags: python, regression, linearmodels

This is similar to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46774707/valueerror-exog-does-not-have-full-column-rank).

I'm running a [2-stage least square regression](https://bashtage.github.io/linearmodels/doc/iv/methods.html#linearmodels.iv.model.IV2SLS) with set of categorical variables.

I've run the model successfully once but when I tried to replicate the model it ran into this error:  **ValueError: instruments [exog instruments]  do not have full column rank**

As far as I can tell this is related to my exogenous variable missing data or having fewer rows than my other variables. However, the constant was created using this method:

```
df['const'] = 1
controls = ['const'] + controls
```

which simply adds column called 'const' to my dataframe and then adds this to my list of control variables (instruments).

I've also checked the dataframe with the new 'const' column was created and added correctly.

Any insight would be much, much appreciated.

thanks!